# SQL relationship confusion

Tags: sql

I usually don't have a problem working with the database at work, yes their structure is confusing. But, I can get by... Well, I'm supposed to produce a query in which it will display every account WITHOUT a user that has a CEO role or Admin role.

Each account has at least 3 Users, and each User can have up to 10 different roles. Including Admin or CEO.

### Cols

`AK_lAccountID` = ID corresponding to account

`sAcctName` = Account Name

`PK_lCustomerID` = ID corresponding to customer Identification

### Tables

`tUsers` = Table to store user values

`tCustomers` = Table to store customer values(ID, name, status, etc.)

`tSalesStatus` = Table to store what sales status

`tUserRoles` = Table to store User Roles( admin, CEO, User, etc.)

```
sSQLs = " SELECT DISTINCT   AK_lAccountID, sAcctName, PK_lCustomerID " & _
    " FROM              tUsers u, tCustomers c, tSalesStatuses ss, tRegions r, tUserRoles ur " & _
    " WHERE             u.FK_lCustomerID = PK_lCustomerID AND " & _
    "                   u.FK_lRegionID = PK_lRegionID AND " & _
    "                   PK_lRegionID = 1 AND " & _
    "                   c.FK_lSalesStatusID = ss.PK_lSalesStatusID AND " & _
    "                   FK_lSalesStatusID = 8 AND " & _
    "                   ur.FK_lUserID = PK_lUserID AND " & _
    "                   ur.FK_lRoleID = FK_lRoleID AND " & _
    "                   FK_lRoleID NOT IN (3, 15) " & _
    " GROUP BY          AK_lAccountID, sAcctName, PK_lCustomerID " & _
    " HAVING            COUNT(*) >= 2 " & _
    " ORDER BY          sAcctName "
```

Also, Users can have multiple roles.

Anyway, for some reason, it's just pulling all records. Even if it has a CEO user or Admin.

Also forgot to mention, the user roles are INT values.

CEO = 15
Admin = 3

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? mysql <> sql server. Also, you should stop using the old style join syntax. Explicit join syntax has been around for more than 20 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins Also, if you add the alias to each of your columns it is much clearer where the data comes from.

Comment: We use SQL server 2008, and I keep the code the way they want it, but yes, it is uber confusing... So, what do you mean adding the alias?

Comment: My meaning is to add the alias at the front of your column names (u.AK_lAccountID etc). That way other people can easily determine which table a given column belongs to. It also saves you hassles when you change the query and the same column is in both tables.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use exists -clause for this. Since your database structure isn't 100% clear to me, I would assume you need something like this:

```
SELECT
  AK_lAccountID, 
  sAcctName, 
  PK_lCustomerID 
FROM
  tCustomers c, 
  tSalesStatuses ss, 
  tRegions r
WHERE
  PK_lRegionID = 1 AND 
  c.FK_lSalesStatusID = ss.PK_lSalesStatusID AND 
  FK_lSalesStatusID = 8 AND 
  not exists (
    select 1
    from
      tUsers u
      join tUserRoles ur on ur.FK_lUserID = u.PK_lUserID
    where
      u.FK_lCustomerID = c.PK_lCustomerID AND 
      u.FK_lRegionID = r.PK_lRegionID AND 
      ur.FK_lRoleID IN (3, 15))
ORDER BY
  sAcctName
```

Or at least you'll be able to figure out the way from this.

Comment: At least region is slightly unclear that how it relates to all of this, now it's probably causing extra rows into the select

Comment: This pulled records from the wrong region. The region we want is 1, PK_lRegionID = 1

Comment: I tried tweaking it, I just think the whole structure of our database is the problem.

Comment: @NicholasStrydom Yes the region is probably wrong because I didn't understand how it's related to the data.

Answer (score 0):

This is of course not tested and it more than likely going to need some tweaks to columns because I had to make guesses about what columns are where but something like this should be pretty close.

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.AK_lAccountID
    , c.sAcctName
    , c.PK_lCustomerID
FROM tUsers u
join tCustomers c on u.FK_lCustomerID = c.PK_lCustomerID
join tSalesStatuses ss on c.FK_lSalesStatusID = ss.PK_lSalesStatusID
join tRegions r on u.FK_lRegionID = r.PK_lRegionID
join tUserRoles ur on ur.FK_lUserID = u.PK_lUserID 
                AND ur.FK_lRoleID = u.FK_lRoleID
WHERE PK_lRegionID = 1 
    AND FK_lSalesStatusID = 8 
    AND FK_lRoleID NOT IN (3, 15)
GROUP BY u.AK_lAccountID
    , c.sAcctName
    , c.PK_lCustomerID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN ur.RoleName IN ('CEO', 'Admin') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
ORDER BY c.sAcctName
```

Comment: This didn't run at all. But, I was hoping this was the closest because I have been trying joins ever since I posted my original code

Comment: What does "This didn't run at all" mean? I had to make a LOT of guesses here because I have no idea what your actual tables are like.

Comment: No worries, I don't understand most of it either. I do know that I think the join is the right idea, I just don't know how to implement it properly.